# Delete state of column ($ sign) from named range

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use named range adress but it is for example $I$7 and I want to use I$7. I tried in below case but it does not work correctly. I want to put the adress (I$7) in conditional formatting formula.

```
AdresNamedRange1 = Range("SomeRange1").Address
AdresNamedRange2 = Range("SomeRange2").Address

MsgBox AdresNamedRange1
MsgBox AdresNamedRange2

adr1 = Mid(SomeRange1, 2)
adr2 = Mid(SomeRange2, 2)

MsgBox adr1
MsgBox adr2
```

First 2 Msgboxes show adresses with 2 $.
Second 2 Msgboxes show adress without first $.

If I put adr1 and adr2 in conditional formarring formula it does not work the same as absolute ranges. Thanks in advance for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Range().Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) provides for this functionality.

```
AdresNamedRange1 = Range("SomeRange1").Address(1, 0)
AdresNamedRange2 = Range("SomeRange2").Address(1, 0)
```

With `Set SomeRange1 = Range("A1")` the `AdresNamedRange1` string var would be `A$1`.